# Trigger constraint violation occurred in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I'm using the GridDB Node js connector to do data analysis using the CSV file that I saved in the GridDB container, and I'm getting the following error:

```
[Server]: 140001/145001/170003/10040

[Description] (Trigger constraint violation)
```

As far as I know, this error is generated by the "Container::createTrigger()" function if the trigger name is null or blank or if the update operation subject to monitoring is not specified. But I haven't called this function anywhere in the code, so I'm curious about what could have caused this possible error. Any recommendations?

P.S. The relevant code is attached below.

```js
var griddb =  require('griddb-node-api');

const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  path: 'out.csv',
  header: [
      {id: "country", title: "country"},
      {id: "daily oil consumption (barrels)", title: "daily oil consumption (barrels)"},
      {id: "world share", title: "world share"},
      {id: "yearly gallons per capita", title: "yearly gallons per capita"},
      {id: "price per gallon (USD)", title: "price per gallon(USD)"},
      {id: "price per liter (USD)", title: "price per liter (USD)"},
      {id: "price per liter (PKR)", title: "price per liter (PKR)"}
  ]
});

const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
const store = factory.getStore({
    "host": '239.0.0.1',
    "port": 31999,
    "clusterName": "defaultCluster",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
});

const conInfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "globalfluctuationsfuelprices",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["country", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["daily oil consumption (barrels)", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
      ["world share", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["yearly gallons per capita", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
      ["price per gallon (USD)", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
      ["price per liter (USD)", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
      ["price per liter (PKR)", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});

...
```